# Add midpoints into array and use them in the next iteration

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, gd

It sounds very basic but I can't get my head around this:
I have two points representing X:Y coordinates
In the first iteration i want to add the midpoint of the two into the array...
In the next iteration i want to add the midpoint of the first and the second and then the midpoint between the second and the third one into the array... and so on...
(Im adding random amounts to the y axis to do midpoint displacement)
E.g.
0:10, 10:10
first iteration...
0:10, 5:13, 10:10
Second iteration...
0:10, 2.5:12, 5:13, 7.5:15, 10:10
etc. etc.

this is the code i ended up with after trying to get at least something to work:

```
<?php
 header('Content-type: image/png');
  $png_image = imagecreate(1024, 1024);
  imagecolorallocate($png_image, 15, 142, 210);
  $black = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 0, 0, 0);
    imagesetthickness($png_image, 10);

$iterations = 5;
$noise = 10;

$points = array("0:512","1023:512");

for($iteration=0; $iteration < $iterations; $iteration++){

        $new_array = array();
        ksort($points);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($points)-1 ;$i++){
        $previous = array("X" => split(":", $points[$i])[0], "Y" => split(":", $points[$i])[1] );
        $next  = array("X" => split(":", $points[$i+1])[0], "Y" => split(":", $points[$i+1])[1] );

        $midpoint = ($previous["X"] + $next["X"])/2;
        $midheight = (($previous["Y"] + $next["Y"])/2)+rand(0,$noise);

        $npoint="$midpoint:$midheight";


        array_push($new_array, $npoint);
    }
    $points =  array_merge($points, $new_array);

}


ksort($points);
for($i=0;$i < sizeof($points)-1;$i++){
        $previous = array("X" => split(":", $points[$i])[0], "Y" => split(":", $points[$i])[1] );
        $current  = array("X" => split(":", $points[$i+1])[0], "Y" => split(":", $points[$i+1])[1] );
     // imageline($png_image, (int)$previous["X"], (int)$previous["Y"], (int)$current["X"], (int)$current["Y"], $black);
    // imagefilledellipse ( $png_image ,(int)$previous["X"], (int)$previous["Y"] , 8, 8 , $black );
    imagestring ($png_image , 4 , (int)$previous["X"], (int)$previous["Y"] , $i , $black);

}


 imagepng($png_image);
 imagedestroy($png_image);
?>
```

for some reason it adds points at the same x sometimes but with different y value.

EDIT:attempt with a function

```
$iterations = 5;
$noise = 10;

$points = array("0:512","1023:512");

$cit = 0;
function divide($pointArray){
    global $noise, $cit, $iterations;  
    $arrayLength = sizeof($pointArray);
    $tempArray = $pointArray;
    for($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength-1 ;$i++){
        $currentPoint = array("X" => split(":", $pointArray[$i])[0], "Y" => split(":", $pointArray[$i])[1] );
        $nextPoint  = array("X" => split(":", $pointArray[$i+1])[0], "Y" => split(":", $pointArray[$i+1])[1] );

        $midpoint = ($currentPoint["X"] + $nextPoint["X"])/2;
        $midheight = (($currentPoint["Y"] + $nextPoint["Y"])/2)+rand(0,$noise);

        $npoint="$midpoint:$midheight";
        array_splice( $tempArray, $i+$i, 0, $npoint );
        $cit++;
        if($cit < $iterations){
            divide($tempArray);
        }else{
            return $tempArray;
        }
```

Comment: how the 13 comes in first iteration

Comment: @siddhesh the y value starts at 10 and a random value is added to it

Comment: use recursion to acheive the desired result

Comment: @siddhesh what is the advantage of recursion over just looping in this case?

Comment: there will be the less confusion...

Comment: @siddhesh i added a new attempt using a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you risk to have errors or warnings during execution, which will be output as part of the image, and that will make your image invalid.

So while developing, you should remove the `header` statement, to make sure you spot all error messages. And indeed, when I do that with your code, I get:

> **E_DEPRECATED :** type 8192 -- Function split() is deprecated

So, you would first need to solve that. And as we speak of that code, may I suggest you do not use the "X:Y" format: it is very inefficient to store the coordinates that way. You are unpacking that string into X, Y coordinates in every iteration, and then convert it back to string. Why not store the array values in X, Y numerical coordinates from the start?

Here is the suggested code:

```
<?php
$png_image = imagecreate(1024, 1024);
imagecolorallocate($png_image, 15, 142, 210);
$black = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 0, 0, 0);
imagesetthickness($png_image, 10);

$iterations = 5;
$noise = 10;

// Don't use string format "X:Y" for doing manipulations. 
// If you still need that format afterwards, do that conversion later.
$points = array(
    array(
        "X" => 0,
        "Y" => 512
    ),
    array(
        "X" => 1023,
        "Y" => 512
    )
);

for($iteration=0; $iteration < $iterations; $iteration++){
    $new_array = array($points[0]);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($points)-1; $i++){
        $previous = $points[$i];
        $next  = $points[$i+1];

        $midpoint = array(
            "X" => ($previous["X"] + $next["X"])/2,
            "Y" => ($previous["Y"] + $next["Y"])/2 + rand(0,$noise)
        );

        array_push($new_array, $midpoint);
        array_push($new_array, $next);
    }
    $points =  $new_array;
}

for($i=0; $i < sizeof($points)-1; $i++){
    $previous = $points[$i];
    $next  = $points[$i+1];
    imagestring ($png_image , 4 , (int)$previous["X"], (int)$previous["Y"] , $i , $black);

}

// Put header statement in comments for as long as you have errors:
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($png_image);
imagedestroy($png_image);

?>
```

Comment: It did, sorry it took me a while to respond.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much in terms of php, but let me try to help with the general logic.
Code example is in javascript, but I can try to explain.

```
var midPointDisplace = function(pt1, pt2, depth, accum){
    // Create the mid point.
    var pt3 = [(pt1[0] + pt2[0]) / 2 + (Math.random()-0.5), (pt1[1] + pt2[1]) / 2 + (Math.random()-0.5)]; 
    if (depth == 0){
        // if the recursion depth reaches 0. Push the midpoint in to the accumulator array.
        accum.push(pt3);
    }else{
        // Otherwise, recurse down.
        midPointDisplace(pt1, pt3, depth - 1, accum); // Ask the next depth in the recursion to generate the points between pt1 (previous point) and pt3 (current mid point).
        accum.push(pt3); // Push/append the current midpoint
        midPointDisplace(pt3, pt2, depth - 1, accum); // Ask the next depth in the recursion to generate the points between pt3 and pt2 (the next point).
    }
}
```

Above is the main "workhorse" of the logic, in essence, it's tasked to generate all the midpoint between pt1 and pt2, and recursive as necessary.
The above loop can be initialize as below.

```
var initPoint = function(pt1, pt2, depth, accum){
    accum.push(pt1); // Push the first point.
    midPointDisplace(pt1, pt2 ,depth, accum); // Generate all the mid points.
    accum.push(pt2); // Push the last point.
}
```

The "accum" property should be passed as reference to allow each step in the recursion to "build it up".  After the function return, accum will contain what you want.

The "depth" property essentially states how many times you want to do the mid-point generation.